# The hmac(sha1) has different result between postman and python

Tags: javascript, python, json, postman, hmacsha1

my code has different result between postman and python,and I hope that the results of Python execution are consistent with Postman.

- Postman

```
var secret = 'gourds';
var mmd5 = 'sha1=' + CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(params)),secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

- Python

```py
hmac.new(str.encode('gourds'),json.dumps(json.loads(md,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)),sha1).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I find the reason.
because the content is different. Extra spaces in python scripts and incorrect encoding

```py
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
...
json.dumps(json.loads(md,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict),separators=(',',':'),ensure_ascii=False)
```